# Why is "switch-case" considering a #define'd identifier as constant but not a const-qualified variable?

Tags: c, switch-statement, constants, c-preprocessor

This program produces the following error:

> case label does not reduce to an integer constant|

I simply fail to understand why an explicitly declared constant `third_cond`, assigned initializer `3`, that too inside the function body, is not considered a constant for `case 3` while a `#define`'d identifier `second_value` is considered a constant at the same time.The program works fine if I use the literal `3` instead of `third_cond` or simply `#define` `third_cond` as `3`. Please explain why it's so, unless this question is a duplicate. I checked,but didn't find an answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define second_cond 2

int main()
{
   const int third_cond=3;
   int choice;
   printf("Enter your choice\n");
   scanf("%d",&choice);

   switch(choice)
   {
       case 1:
       printf("Beggar");
       break;
       case second_cond:
       printf("Mugger");
       break;
       case third_cond:
       printf("Lugger");
       break;
       default:
       printf("Bugger");
   }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to get a firm handle on all the basics, which is excellent. A good place to lurk is [comp.lang.c](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/comp.lang.c). I've learned loads of stuff from those guys (most of them are here, too).

Comment: @luserdroog Since you've clearly suggested that, I'll check that out.Lets' hope it's for average learners like me, not for programming aces.

Comment: Just like SO, it's for both. But usenet is a different format. It's much more like a huge email list. No moderation. Although the regulars make great efforts to keep things on topic. (There is a separate moderated group, but it's much less active.) But you don't have to be an ace to enjoy watching the aces argue.

Comment: @luserdroog I am indeed trying to understand the basics well as I am not that good in programming.But I am amazed how you managed to notice that.What made you draw the conclusion?I am sure you didn't conclude from a single question of mine.Do you know me from before as I use this alias elsewhere too,and long before I joined SO.(SO is  honestly a little formidable for absolute beginners!!)

Comment: Can't speak for luser droog, but it's not that hard to notice. You're often asking for further explanations in comments on others' answers when you are not aware of some of the finer points of the matter. Once you've seen a particular user name a handful of times, you recognize it (if it's not something like user123654). Keep being inquisitive, you'll be considered an expert sooner than you expect.

Comment: I just noticed you in the past few days. A couple comments seemed pretty sharp. (Asking for more explanation from short answers.) So it just occurred to me, that you really need to know about comp.lang.c if you don't already.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've some serious short-comings to overcome,major crippling one is being absolute stranger to the world of Linux,UNIX-like OSes,and anything open-source.Pampered for long by "Uncle Gates" and regretting now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C `const` does not mean constant but read-only. A `const` qualified variable is never a constant and cannot be used where a constant expression is required.

Note that you can also use `enum` constants for the `case` constant expression as `enum` constants are real constants.

Comment: I never knew `enum` variables are constants,paradoxical as that statement sounds!!

Comment: So enum variables are constants eh?What is the correct way to phrase my statement? enum `variables are constants` sounds odd.

Comment: No, `enum` variables are not constants. But `enum` members are constants.

Comment: Thanks.Never thought of that.

Comment: What's the point waiting for better answers?I doubt anyone can better yours.Anyways, lets wait a little, but please reply to my comment above about `global variables in C`.

Comment: @SheerFish this is off-topic in this question, but yes there are no global variable in C for the sole reason there is no global scope. There are file scope variables in C and it is what people usually refer to when they talk about global variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I suppose you were away from your computer.The guy who mentioned it to me has explained it clearly to me now.

Comment: OK,accepting your answer now.8 upvotes is enough of a testimony to its quality.

Answer (score 1):

A constant is literally a value : `"string constant"`, `1L`, `0.5`, `0xAF`, ...

You can define your own constants with `enum` :

```
enum
{
    MY_CONSTANT_1,
    MY_CONSTANT_2,
    /* ... */
}
```

The `switch-case` wait for constants that can be casted to `int` (so, `enum`, `int`, `long`, ...).

A `#define` declare a macro, so at compile-time, `second_cond` is replaced by `2`, which is a constant.

But `third_cond` still remains a variable, a read-only variable (because of `const`), so, there is no guarantee that it's value stay the same (even with the presence of `const` which mark only the identifier as read-only, and not the associated memory).

Comment: Nit picking: "*A #define declare a macro, so at compile-time, second_cond is replaced by 2 ...*" should read: "*... so at compile-time, second_cond **had already been** replaced by 2 **by the pre-processor** ...*"

Comment: @alk: In spite of the name “preprocessing”, macro expansion is, as defined by the C standard, a part of the translation of C source code to an executable program, not something that occurs before translation begins. It is translation phase four of eight.